# Equivalence of distributions of a stochastic process under equivalent measures

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I am currently trying to understand some foundations of stochastic processes. My teacher mentioned the following fact:

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, \mathbf{P})$ be a probability space and $\{\xi_t\}_{t \in T}$ - a stochastic process defined on this space, $\mathbf{Q}$ is a measure on $\Omega$, equivalent to $\mathbf{P}$ (so corresponding null sets are equal). Then the distribution of $\{\xi_t\}_{t \in T}$ under measure $\mathbf{Q}$ is equivalent to the distribution of $\{\xi_t\}_{t \in T}$ under "old" measure $\mathbf{P}$.

I'm having troubles with proving this fact, which seems basic. I've tried some shenanigans with $\pi$-systems (however, the minimal $\sigma$-algebra, generated by null sets, is less than $\mathcal{B}$, so got nothing good here). I'm not familiar with Radon-Nikodym stuff, but, I guess, there should be an easier way to deal with it.

Can someone point me the right direction to prove it?

Thanks!

Comment: Take any finite collection of $m$ those random variables, for some positive integer $m$. Take any Borel measurable subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$. The probability that the variables are in the set $B$, as defined by the joint CDF, is the same as that defined by the original measure. So it will be zero if and only if it is zero under the original measure.